# Determining the value of Rc if Vbe =0.7 V, • Vce = 0.2 V et • β=40

Tags: current, bjt

I have to light a LED with a NPN, so this is cool, I just pick a base resistor so that i have a collector to base current lower than the led's max rating

But I also have a coil to keep in mind, which is supposed to trigger a relay.

It has that weird rating that does not ring any bell: 12V@100mA

is the voltage at the coil going to vary depending on the current passing through it? I dont understand.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The 12 V/100 mA rating means that the coil is intended to be operated on 12 volts, and will draw 100 mA at that voltage.

If you really have a high-power LED rated for 250 mA, you can connect it as shown. The value of Rc should be chosen to drop about 5.5 volts at 100 mA.

Comment: thanks, and it isn't a max rating, right? since i have a source of 20V, and the led has a vdrop of 2.5, i should have 17.5V at the coil.. note that this is a theoretical exercice, i am just trying to understand how these circuits work

Comment: If you choose Rc to drop 5.5 volts at 100 mA, that and the 2.5 V drop on the LED, will eave 12 volts for the relay coil.

Answer (score 1):

It's way simpler if you put the led in parallel to the coil, *unless* you need to keep the led off if the coil or the wiring for some reason breaks (for safety, for instance).

[image: First schematic]

The resistor in series for the coil should be of appropriate power rating, of course. As I said, this has the disadvantage of not showing the real state of the current inside the coil. In this case you could do this:

[image: Second schematic]

This is a little trickier to design: the coil need 100mA, but the LED only handle, say, 20mA. So there's a shunt resistor in parallel to the LED to bypass the extra current.

Also, the LED itself has some Vf tolerance and the coil has some resistance tolerance as well, so it becomes a min-maxing exercise.

First of all you can completely ignore the recirculating diode, since it's not conducting anyway.

In short the voltage plan is:

- dropping about 12V on the coil;
- dropping the led Vf on the LED+its shunt resistor;
- dropping the remaining of the supply on the top resistor;
- actually, there's a small Vce drop but I purposely ignore it to have some safety margin for the current.

The current are as follows:

- The current on the top resistor and the coil is the nominal coil current;
- The current on the led is its nominal 10-20mA (or whatever the LED calls for);
- The current on the LED shunt is the remaining current;

Applying the usual circuit laws gives you suitable values for the resistors. At the end verify that everything works in the various tolerance extremes (led max If and coil min pickup voltage are the most important ones). I'd ignore the If dependance for Vf for the led since it's not really important here.

EDIT: I noticed your If max for the led is 250mA… is this some kind of power led? You should do the calculation for the nominal If but beware that they are quite sensitive to current variations (they are really meant to be driven by constant current generators); *maybe* you'll need to take in account the V/I curve for the diode, in that case.

If your LED If is actually bigger than you coil current you simply have to move the shunt in parallel to the coil, instead. The basic idea remains the same.